# How to create a custom header menu for Webix datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, datatable, webix

I'm trying to create a custom menu for an icon in the datatable header. The main idea is to show this menu for the one specific column (on icon click)
Here's my current code:

http://webix.com/snippet/b5259f40

```
{ 
  view:"datatable", 
  columns:[
    { id:"info",    header:"Info", fillspace:1},
    { id:"props",   header:"<i id='settings' class='fa fa-list' style='text-align:center;'></i>",   width:150}    
  ],
  data:[], 
  on:{
    onHeaderClick:function(id, e, node){
      $$("mymenu").show(node);
    }
  }
});

webix.ui({
  view:"popup",      
  body:{    
    view:"menu", data:[],
    on:{
      onMenuItemClick:function(id){
        webix.message(id);
        this.getParentView().hide()
      }
    }
})
```

For now, the popup opens when I click anywhere in the header.

How can I append menu for the icon only? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[update]**

You are required to add an **onClick** function for your icon. In order to align the popup window with the icon, you have to manually adjust its **x and y offsets** according to your needs. Please check below:

```
onClick:{
  "fa": function(id, e, node){  //"fa" is the classname in your header
        $$("mymenu").show(
       {
          x : 780,            //left offset from the right side
          y : 30              //top offset
       });
   }
}
```

Please check the snippet [here](http://webix.com/snippet/972f9dca).

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question - is it possible to append the menu window to the icon instead of the column? IMHO it will look much better. If it's possible, of course